# No module named 'mmcv._ext'

Tags: python, pytorch, openmmlab

Tried to train the model but got the mmcv error

```
No module named 'mmcv._ext'
```

mmcv library is already installed and imported

```
mmcv version = 1.4.0
Cuda version = 10.0
```

Any suggestions to fix the issue??

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmdetection/issues/3271

> There basically are two workarounds.
>
> ```
> Install latest mmdet and pip install mmcv-full or install pre-build ones from here.
> Install mmcv==0.6.2 and mmdet==2.2.1
> ```

or try

> first: pip uninstall mmcv then: pip install
> mmcv-full==latest+torch1.5.0+cu101 -f
> https://download.openmmlab.com/mmcv/dist/index.html my mmdet version
> is 2.4.0, mmcv>=1.1.0

Comment: Just to complement this answer, using their repo management instead of pip helped me: install the  `pip install -U openmim`, and then  `mim install mmcv`, which installed the version `mmcv==2.0.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

`mmcv==0.6.2 and mmdet==2.3.0` this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the installation guideline to install mmedit?

You can try the following steps to fix:

1. pip uninstall mmcv-full
2. pip install mmcv
3. re-run this program, make sure it raise ImportError: mmcv not found
4. reinstall mmcv-full with pip install openmim; mim install mmcv-full,
   or other version based on your requirements.
5. import mmcv._ext to verify.

Answer (score 0):

I have face same issue with mmcv-full [v1.6.0], mmdet [2.24.0], torch [1.9.0] + CUDA [11.1] and I cant use another version of mmcv-full due to certain dependencies. If you are stuck like me and want a very raw solution.

It is found that the missing module mmcv._ext is a installation generated file  '/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmcv/**_ext.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so**'.  Somehow, mmcv-full[1.6.0] pip/mim installation didn't generate me this file. So I had to install mmcv-full[1.7.2] which generated this specific **_ext.cpythonblablablah** file and then I copied it to mmcv-full[1.6.0] installation folder and am using it just fine.